# Cannot add subsites in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sub-site

We have a new install of Sharepoint 2013 Full Trial version. We cannot add any subsites; we get the following error:

> Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, 
>      Culture=neutral,
>     PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing post on this but it doesn't have any answers. so I am referring that [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134594/why-do-i-get-a-runtime-error-when-i-try-to-create-an-new-subsite)

Few troubleshooting tips:

1. What is the error log details telling ?
2. Share more details on the farm or confirm it as a single server environment
3. Did you tried with admin rights ?
4. Try running config wizard once again or do an iisreset and then try again.